# Using custom HTML tags to WordPress

Tags: html, editor, css

Similar to, for example, `<blockquotes>`, I also work with, for example, custom `<blocktips>` styled with :before and :after elements to be used regularly on a site. After styling, these are added in the Text editor as `<blocktip>Text here</blocktip>`.

The problem is that when I go back to the Visual editor, these elements are removed from the code and has to be added again before Updating.

In my case, is there a way to prevent the WordPress editor from removing these custom HTML tags.

Comment: `<blocktip>` is [no valid HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). Is there a specific reason you're trying to do it this way instead of `<span class="blocktip">` or similar?

Comment: @kero It's for my Mom's website. I'm trying to simplify things to the max for her.

Comment: While I appreciate your intention (making it easy for the user) this doesn't change anything about the fact that this is not a valid HTML tag. You can't/shouldn't just invent new tags like that.

Comment: @kraftner I ended up using opening and closing shortcode tags with CSS classes instead. Just as easy, less interference from 'TinyMCE' easier to style and safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand list of KSES allowed tags (and their attributes):

```
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', 'wpse_283385_blocktip_tag');
function wpse_283385_blocktip_tag($allowed_tags) {
    $allowed_tags['blocktip'] = array(
        'name' => true,
        'id' => true,
        'class' => true,
        'style' => true
    );

    return $allowed_tags;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_283385_blocktip_tag_tinymce');
function wpse_283385_blocktip_tag_tinymce($init) {
    $tags = 'blocktip[*]';

    if ( isset( $init['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $init['extended_valid_elements'].= ','.$tags;
    } else {
        $init['extended_valid_elements'] = $tags;
    }

    return $init;
}
```

If you need more attributes for that tag, add them in the array in the first function, or add them to $tags (comma separated) in the second.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to include code for TinyMCE editor too.

Comment: The TinyMCE editor filter did the trick. Thank you.